# How necessary is "Option -Multiviews" in Laravel's htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, shared-hosting

When you create a new project with Laravel, a .htaccess file is installed in the public folder. The third line is:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

I am deploying an app to a shared hosting (bad idea, I know, but it is a client's constraint) and their Apache Server doesn't allow the "Options" directive. If I comment that line everything seems to work fine, but I am hesitant to go this way.

Therefore, I would like to know if I could live without that directive, or if disabling it may cause further problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MultiViews takes care of content negotiation (a mechanism used by Apache to choose which file to serve when the choice is ambiguous; [more on the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options)). Actually the line `Options -MultiViews` disables the option for the folder; however, since it should not be enabled by default, you should be ok by ignoring it.